# Cannot display the uploaded files on the "Input Files" button

Tags: javascript

Is there any reason as to why I cannot get the Upload button to display the name of the file(s) uploaded despite copying exactly the tutorial on YouTube - see link below?

In the tutorial `e` is used for the `eventListener` function in JS, but Adobe Dreamweaver is having none of it, so I used `addEventListener`

Thanks in advance for any insight. :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JML3BZo_ToA&list=PLQ0Y5YcHFmjVCFO7t1_72VU2FiXo5XaEI&index=1

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 "use strict";

 $("#uploadBtn").on("change", function(){
  
  var files = $(this)[0].files;
  
  if(files.length >= 2){
   
   $("#label_span").text(files.length + " files ready to upload");
   
  } else {
   
   var filename = addEventListener.target.value.split('\\').pop();
   $("#label_span").text(filename);
  }
  
 });
 
});
```

```css
.uploadFile{
 height: auto;
 padding: 30px;
 background-color: #E0DDDD;
 color: #797979;
}
#uploadBtn{
 display: none;
 width: auto;
}
.uploadButtonLabel{
 font-size:18px;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 border-style: none;
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
.uploadButtonLabel:before{
 font-family: fontAwesome;
 content: "\f093";
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.uploadButtonLabel:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS Documents/bookCastingJS.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="uploadFile">
 <h2>Upload your documents...</h2>
 <p>Please ensure that you upload your require documents. Failure to do will may delay your applications.</p>
 <label for="uploadBtn" class="uploadButtonLabel calltoActionButton" id="label_span">Select file(s) to upload</label>
 <input style="width: 25%;" type="file" id="uploadBtn" name="upload" multiple = "true" />
</div>
<script src="bookCastingJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: why are you using addEventListener?  if you just want the name of the file(s) you can pull them from the `files` object.

Comment: I'm just following the tutorial. What's the alteration to the code for your suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use your `files` variable instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $("#uploadBtn").on("change", function() {

    var files = $(this)[0].files;
    if (!files) return;

    if (files.length > 1) {

      $("#label_span").text(files.length + " files ready to upload");

    } else {

      var filename = files[0].name;
      $("#label_span").text(filename);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.uploadFile {
  height: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #E0DDDD;
  color: #797979;
}

#uploadBtn {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
}

.uploadButtonLabel {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border-style: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.uploadButtonLabel:before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: "\f093";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.uploadButtonLabel:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS Documents/bookCastingJS.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="uploadFile">
  <h2>Upload your documents...</h2>
  <p>Please ensure that you upload your require documents. Failure to do will may delay your applications.</p>
  <label for="uploadBtn" class="uploadButtonLabel calltoActionButton" id="label_span">Select file(s) to upload</label>
  <input style="width: 25%;" type="file" id="uploadBtn" name="upload" multiple="true" />
</div>
<script src="bookCastingJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: FFS, now its not working in DW. Works perfectly on here, but not responding the external JS sheet. I've never work with such a retarded programme in my entire life.